# in angularjs dropdown data comming from database but not showing in menu

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

Here im using Mvc with Angularjs  Here im getting Data From database but why dropdown not display vale values this is my Html coding

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="margin-left:20px">
         <b>Country</b>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
         <select ng-model="CountryID" ng-options="I.CountryID as I.CountryName for I in CountyList" ng-change="GetStates()">
            <option value="">Country</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**angular code**

```
 function Getcountrys(){
        var ddd = Mysercive.BindCntryList();

       ddd.then(function (d) {
           $scope.CountyList = d.data;
        })
    }
```

Comment: print ur CountyList JSON and verify the keys (CountryName..) if it matches which u have given in ng-options

Comment: What is the value of $scope.CountryID?

Comment: this is my linqcode  var x = from n in db.Countries
                    select n;              return new JsonResult { Data = x, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
but not working

Comment: here my code working fine when i write outside div but not working ing div tag